# What is the time complexity for getting the size of a heap?

Tags: data-structures, heaps

Assuming the regular Heap ADT.

What is the time complexity of getting its size ?

I tend to think that because insert is O(log(n)), then I always know the last index of my heap. So in order to get its size all I need is to return the last index + 1.

However I have seen in some places that refer to the size of the heap's complexity as O(n), since I need to count all the nodes in my heap.

Why am I wrong ?

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about an ADT, you can't really say. It depends on the implementation. You can certainly do it in O(1) (for example by keeping a counter).

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how you implement your ADT heap. You can expand `size` as a counter of `next` operations. In that manner, if you are using

- an external counter: $O(1)$
- a stack: $O(n)$
- a binary tree: $O(logn)$
- a hash: $O(k)$ ($k$ is the average collisions)